# Are query parameters broken in SEDE

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I didn't notice this earlier but for some reason it looks like the [query parameter](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#parameters) functionality is broken for me when editing a query.

If I run this query from the [edit view](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/295728)

```
declare @title nvarchar(50) = ##title:string##
print '|'+ @title +'|'
```

the result is, if I enter test in the title field,

> `|,test|`

Where does that comma at the start come from?

Strangely enough if I simply [run that same query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/295728?title=testg) from the permalink all works as expected, no comma is added.

If I remove the type indicator like so:

```
declare @title nvarchar(50) = ##title##
print '|'+ @title +'|'
```

I'm greeted with an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','. Must declare the scalar variable "@title".

enclosing the parameter in quotes fixes that but then my result is the same as previous, I get an extra comma.

If I added the type again while the query parameter is within quotes like so:

```
declare @title nvarchar(50) = '##title:string##'
print '|'+ @title +'|'
```

I'm back at the previous error.

I tried to move the query parameter out of the declare

```
declare @title nvarchar(50)
set @title = ##title:string##
```

but that didn't help.

I can reproduce this in both IE11 and Google Chrome.

For the time being I'll do a `replace(@title, ',','')`.

If this is indeed a bug, can this be fixed, please?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I found the root-cause.

The field `title` is already submitted in the form. So if you choose your variable names don't use ones that are already part of the payload.

this will work:

```
declare @somevar nvarchar(50) = ##notitle:string##
print '|'+ @somevar +'|'
```

When you hit run the following formdata is submitted:

```
title:
description:
sql:declare @somevar nvarchar(50) = ##notitle:string##
notitle:test
```

With a query parameter called `title` the following payload is posted:

```
title:
description:
sql:declare @somevar nvarchar(50) = ##title:string##
print '|'+ @somevar +'|'
title:test
```

Notice the double `title` in the form parameters

Executing that with a title gives you this result:

[image: SEDE query with double title]

So to prevent this bug/feature don't use the following names for your query parameters:

> `title`
>   `description`
>   `sql`
>   `recaptcha_challenge_field`
>   `recaptcha_response_field`

Comment: Hmm....yeah, that's not ideal. I'll look into fixing it, since `title` in particular seems like it could be a common conflict.

Comment: Yeah, a prefix similar to recaptcha should work. I propose `unicorns_waffles_`