# SEDE does something weird with URL parameters

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks, data-explorer

Can somebody explain what happens in [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1646738?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com&opt.textResults=true)? It's a very simple one, apart from the use of a [parameter](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#parameters):

```
PRINT ('%href="##url##"%')
```

but somehow SEDE decides to append part of its own submit call to the URL I specified as parameter (`https://meta.stackexchange.com`). This is the result:

> %href="https://meta.stackexchange.com,/query/run/4/1646738/2005914"%

but I'd expect the query to produce

> %href="https://meta.stackexchange.com"%

Comment: Related / similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252560/are-query-parameters-broken-in-sede/252572#252572

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're using [`Request.Params`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/QueryController.cs#L90) to give `ParsedQuery` the data to substitute into the query, which is…not the best behaviour here, because of how that is populated. `Request.Form` is probably more appropriate, so we get the values passed in specifically from the form.

I've submitted a PR to resolve this (in a slightly different way than described above), but in the meantime using a different parameter name would avoid the issue.

Comment: Ah, we weren't using `Request.Form` because of the CSV route…

Comment: That gives me a decent workaround, thanks! https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1694315?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there even anyone on the other side of those PR's? Used to be only Nick and he's long gone, so wonder if it's not just waste of time.